# gmock - mocking non-virtual method of the derived class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I am using VS2005 and gmock ver. 1.6 for unit testing.

I have the following code which I want to mock, but I cannot find a way to do so.

```
class A
{
 virtual bool foo1() = 0;
 virtual bool foo2() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
 virutal bool foo1();
 virtual bool foo2();
 static B* getInstance(int x);
 static B* getInstance();
}
```

Where `getInstance(int x)` is just creating an instance of B and returns it. Whereas `getInstance()` just returns the already created instance by `getInstance(int x)`;

I have the mock class,

```
class MockA : public A
{
 MOCK_METHOD0(foo1, bool());
 MOCK_METHOD0(foo2, bool());
}
```

In the sources, I am using

```
bool retVal = B::getInstance()->foo2()
```

How can I mock this behavior `B::getInstance()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use linker seam to do what you want.

Let's say that we have `libraryToBeMocked` with the interface placed in `libraryToBeMocked.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

class Base
{
public:
    virtual bool evenCheck() = 0;
    virtual bool oddCheck() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual bool evenCheck();
    virtual bool oddCheck();
    static Base* getInstance(int x);
    static Base* getInstance();

private:
    Derived(int x);

    int x;
};
```

You should have noticed that I have altered your design. Both `getInstance` method returns pointer to `Base` not `Derived`. If you want to mock the logic clearly you should mock the pure interface Derived already has some logic in it. IMHO both `getInstance` methods should be moved to other class anyways.

The implementation of the library is in `libraryToBeMockedImpl.cpp`

```
#include "libraryToBeMocked.hpp"

#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>

bool Derived::evenCheck() { return x % 2 == 0; }

bool Derived::oddCheck() { return x % 2 != 0; }

namespace
{
    std::auto_ptr<Derived> current(NULL);
}

Base* Derived::getInstance(int x)
{
    current.reset(new Derived(x));

    return current.get();
}

Base* Derived::getInstance()
{
    return current.get();
}

Derived::Derived(int x) : x(x) {}
```

There is also the logic which you want to test. `testedLibrary.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

bool isOdd(int x);
bool isEven(int x);
```

implementation `testedLibraryImpl.cpp`:

```
#include "testedLibrary.hpp"

#include "libraryToBeMocked.hpp"

bool isOdd(int x)
{
    return Derived::getInstance(x)->oddCheck();
}

bool isEven(int x)
{
    return Derived::getInstance(x)->evenCheck();
}
```

Dummy `main` in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "testedLibrary.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    cout << x << " is odd:" << boolalpha << isOdd(x) << endl;
    cout << x << " is even:" << boolalpha << isEven(x) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't use VS, but I think all it takes is to add `main.cpp` `testedLibraryImpl.cpp` and `libraryToBeMockedImpl.cpp` to the project. I would rather use gcc:

```
g++ main.cpp libraryToBeMockedImpl.cpp testedLibraryImpl.cpp -o production
```

Well, let's start with my answer. I would create header file 'libraryMockSeam.hpp':

```
#pragma once

#include "libraryToBeMocked.hpp"

class Provider
{
public:
    virtual Base* getInstance() = 0;
    virtual Base* getInstance(int x) = 0;
};

Provider* registerNewMockProvider(Provider*);
```

and `libraryMockSeam.cpp`:

```
#include "libraryMockSeam.hpp"

namespace
{
Provider* currentProvider = 0;
}

Provider* registerNewMockProvider(Provider* newProvider)
{
    Provider* t = currentProvider;
    currentProvider = newProvider;
    return t;
}

Base* Derived::getInstance()
{
    return currentProvider->getInstance();
}

Base* Derived::getInstance(int x)
{
    return currentProvider->getInstance(x);
}
```

As you can see this source file provides it's own implementation of `getInstance` methods. It delegates it to the registered Provider. The headers introduced the Provider interface and a function that allows to register your provider. That's it.

Let's look at the test:

```
#include "testedLibrary.hpp"
#include "libraryMockSeam.hpp"

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using namespace ::testing;

class MockProvider : public Provider
{
public:
 MOCK_METHOD1(getInstance, Base*(int x));
 MOCK_METHOD0(getInstance, Base*());
};

class MyMock : public Base
{
public:
 MOCK_METHOD0(evenCheck, bool());
 MOCK_METHOD0(oddCheck, bool());
};

class MyTestSuite : public Test
{
public:
    MyTestSuite()
    {
        registerNewMockProvider(&provider);
    }

    StrictMock<MyMock> mock;
    StrictMock<MockProvider> provider;
};

TEST_F(MyTestSuite, checksForOddValue)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(provider, getInstance(1)).Times(2).WillRepeatedly(Return(&mock));

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, evenCheck()).WillOnce(Return(false));
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, oddCheck()).WillOnce(Return(true));

    EXPECT_TRUE(isOdd(1));
    EXPECT_FALSE(isEven(1));
}

TEST_F(MyTestSuite, checksForEvenValue)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(provider, getInstance(1)).Times(2).WillRepeatedly(Return(&mock));

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, evenCheck()).WillOnce(Return(true));
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, oddCheck()).WillOnce(Return(false));

    EXPECT_TRUE(isEven(1));
    EXPECT_FALSE(isOdd(1));
}
```

I would compile it like that:

```
g++ test.cpp testedLibraryImpl.cpp libraryMockSeam.cpp -lgmock -lgmock_main -lpthread -o test
```

You should notice that I did not provide `libraryToBeMocked.cpp` in this case, the implementation is already provided by `libraryMockSeam.cpp`. In case you would like to use whole libraries (that is `*.lib` files(or `*.a`)) You would be able to provide both mocked library and the seam but later one should be provided to the linker before the library.

Comment: Sorry for the dealyed response. Thanks a lot. I will try your solution. I had this in mind, like to create a seam. But I was thinking if there was any other solution as well. I will update here how it works.